# how to get array element from model in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have the following code:

```
Person = new Backbone.Model({
 data:[
    { age: "27" },
    {name: "alamin"}
]
});
```

now, how can I get the value?

```
person=new Person();
person.get(?);
```

Please provide me with a solution.

Comment: Models are supposed to contain scalar data

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should be using Backbone.Model.extend and maybe you mean `defaults` rather than data, as you have given it initial values.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using this model:

```
Person = new Backbone.Model({

data:[
    { age: "27" },
    {name: "alamin"}
]

});
```

So if you want to pull from an array within a model explicitly you should try this:

```
i = new App.Model.Person();
i.fetch();
i.get("data")[0].age;
```

This would return:

```
27
```

From there you can iterate through the data however you prefer.

Comment: How is this answer providing a solution that is different from the other answers that were given years earlier?

Comment: This really helped me with SAPUi5, tho its getProperty("data") there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a data property when defining a model - maybe you mean defaults? as in

```
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
   defaults: {
      property1: value1,
      property2: value2,
      property3: ["arrval1", "arrval2", "arrval3"]
   });
```

You would retrieve the value of certain property using [get](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-get): myperson.get('property1').
To set the value of a property use [set](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set): myperson.set('property1', 'newValueOfProperty')

If a property is an array the myperson.get('property3')[ index ]

Answer (score 0):

To get the array as an object:

Use `person.get('data')`

To get the value of an attribute from the array:

Use `person.get('data').name`

Or  `person.get('data')['name']`

Answer (score 0):

To obtain attributes of a specific element of the array:

```
var people = person.get('data'); // This gets the array of people.
var individual = people[0];      // This gets the 0th element of the array.
var age = individual.age;        // This gets the age property.
var name = individual.name;      // This gets the name property.
```