# How do I access this array in backbone?

Tags: arrays, backbone.js

I’m new to Backbone, but I’ve successfully been able to define an array like this on one of my models:

```
buildMyArray: function() {
    var self = this;

    var myArray = {};

    window.myLibrary.getStuff('myParameter', function(myStuff) {
        for (var myKey in myStuff) {
            if (myStuff.hasOwnProperty(myKey)) {
                var myValue = myStuff[myKey];
                myArray[myKey] = myValue;
            }
        }

        self.set({ myArray: myArray });
    });
}
```

However, how can I access that array from other properties?  In other words, I want to do something like this:

```
checkArrayStuff: function(arrayKey) {
    //loop through myArray and check value for arrayKey.
    //var myArray1 = self.get(myArray);
    //var myArray2 = this.get(myArray);
    //var myArray3 = myArray;
    //var myArray4 = this.myArray;
    //var myArray5 = self.get('myArray');
    //var myArray6 = this.get('myArray');
    var myArray7 = self.myArray;

    var can = myArray7[arrayKey];
    return can;
}
```

I’ve tried several variations of self, this, with-and-without-quotes, with-and-without get-method, etc.

Comment: I don't know backbone, but would this be any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521788/how-to-get-array-element-from-model-in-backbone-js

Comment: Using `get` to access a model attribute should work. We need more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you would have to do this

```
checkArrayStuff: function(arrayKey) {
    return this.get('myArray')[arrayKey];
}
```

Comment: No, "this.get('myArray')" is undefined, so calling [arrayKey] on an undefined object throws an exception.

Comment: You `build my array` first right?  Also what is `myLibrary.getStuff`  is that async?  If it is we may need to introduce some events.

Comment: My real issue was proper sequencing related to async issues, but thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`this.get('myArray')` should work *but* it looks like your `window.myLibrary.getStuff` function is asynchronous. That means `myArray` won't be set until some time after `buildMyArray` returns.  If you give us more context we can make a better recommendation of how to address this such as having buildMyArray call checkArrayStuff after it's done the .set(..) or having buildMyArray return a promise